# DataFrame Pandas for range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have problem with DataFrame for range.
In the first line, I would like to calculate and add the data,
subsequent lines depend on each previous one.
So the first formula is "different", the rest are repeated.
I did this in a DataFrame and it works, but very slowly.
All other data so far is in the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

calc = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(n=10, p=0.2, size=(5,1)))
calc['op_ol'] = calc[0]

calc['op_ol'][0] = calc[0][0]
for ee in range(1,5):
    calc['op_ol'][ee] = 0 if calc['op_ol'][ee-1] == 0 else calc[0][ee-1] * calc['op_ol'][ee-1]
```

How could I speed this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally slow when you use loops with pandas. I suggest you these lines:

```
calc = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(n=10, p=0.2, size=(5,1)))
calc['op_ol'] = (calc[0].cumprod() * calc[0][0]).shift(fill_value=calc[0][0])
```

Where cumprod is the cumulative product and we shift it with the first value.